# Which primes have product equal to their sum plus 1?

Tags: prime-factorization, perfect-numbers

Mathematically speaking, the question is to find all primes $p_i$ such that
$$p_1p_2p_3\cdots p_k = 1+p_1+p_2+\cdots p_k$$
for some positive integer $k$.
I know that the only solutions are $2$ and $3$, but I am unable to figure out a well-written solution.
Regarding the source of the question, I encountered it while proving that $6$ is the only square free perfect number. My proof for that went like this, assume $n$ is any perfect square free number and we wish to prove that $n=6$.
Since, $n$ is square free, we can write the prime factorisation of $n$ as
$$n=p_1p_2\cdots p_k$$
where all $p_i$ are distinct. Now, since $n$ is perfect,
$$n=1+p_1+p_2+\cdots p_k$$
from which we get the original equation.

(PS: This is my first question on Stack Exchange so pardon my mistakes if any.)

As Qiaochu Yuan and Ross Millikan pointed out, I interpreted the meaning of a perfect number in a wrong way, so the original equation becomes
$$2p_1p_2\cdots p_k = (1+p_1)(1+p_2)\cdots (1+p_k)$$
So, it will be helpful if someone brings out any solution to this or even the original problem of 6.
Anyways, I am still interested in solutions to the original equation.

Comment: That's not a correct use of the definition of a perfect number. You've forgotten the divisors like $p_1 p_2, p_2 p_3$, etc. The sum of the divisors of $n$ will end up being $(1 + p_1)(1 + p_2) \dots (1 + p_k) - n$.

Comment: You should write in terms of sets of primes, not primes, because you have $k$ different primes.  Your equation is only correct for numbers that have only two prime factors.  If $n=pq$ for $p,q$ prime, the proper factors of $n$ are $1,p,q$ and your equation works.  If $n$ has three prime factors $n=pqr$ the sum of proper factors is $1+p+q+r+pq+pr+qr$ and you have missed the last three of those.

Comment: In any case, if you're still interested in the original question, it shouldn't be hard to guess that for most values of $p_i$ the LHS will be much larger than the RHS, e.g. $2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 = 210$ is much larger than $1 + 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 18$, and it should be possible to turn this into a proof with some care.

Comment: Indeed, even forgetting that the $p_j$ are primes, you should be able to show that for $k\ge3$, for example, there are no solutions in real numbers $p_j\ge2$ simply by size considerations. And the case $k=2$ is simply a quadratic equation.

Comment: Sorry @Qiaochu Yuan, I really forgot about it. If that's the case, can you provide me an elementary proof of proving that $6$ is the only square free perfect number?

Comment: A product of distinct primes $n = p_1 \dots p_k$ is a perfect number iff we have $2p_1 \dots p_k = (1 + p_1) \dots (1 + p_k)$. Now consider the largest power of $2$ dividing each side.

Comment: Thanks Qiaochu Sir, using that fact, I have completed my proof. As for any $k>3$, RHS is divisible by 4 which LHS can't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WLOG assume that $p_1\le p_2\le \dots\le p_k$. Then $p_1\cdots p_k\le 1+kp_k$. Since each $p_i\ge 2$, we have $2^{k-1}p_k\le 1+kp_k$ or $2^{k-1}\le 1/p_k+k\le k+1$. This implies $k=1$ or $2$. $k=1$ is clearly impossible. So $k=2$, $p_1p_2=1+p_1+p_2$. If $p_1=2$  we have $2p_2=3+p_2$, $p_2=3$.

Suppose that $p_1\ge 3$. So $3p_2\le 1+p_1+p_2$, $2p_2\le p_1+1$ which is impossible for primes $p_1\le p_2$. Hence the answer is $k=2, p_1=2, p_2=3$.

Comment: Can you make it clear how you got the equation $2^{k-1}p_k\leq k+1$?

Comment: NOTE: All the $p_i$ are distinct so it will be wrong to put those $\leq$ signs, instead put $<$ signs.

Comment: $\le$ was put by somebody who edited the question. It works with it too.

Comment: But what about that $2^{k-1}p_k\leq k+1$ line?

Comment: @ultralegend5385: This is not an inequality from the answer. The correct inequality is explained in the answer: " Since each $p_i\ge 2$, we have $2^{k-1}p_k\le 1+kp_k$ or $2^{k-1}\le 1/p_k+k\le k+1$." What part of this explanation is not clear?

Comment: That how you got that power of the $2$ and that what is $1/p_k+k$ exactly, is it $\frac{1}{p_k}+k$ or anything else or what?

Comment: The product is $(p_1p_2...p_{k-1})p_k$. Here each prime in brackets is $\ge 2$, so the product in brackets is at least  $2^{k-1}$ and the whole product is at least $2^{k-1}p_k$. Which must be at most $1+kp_k$. Now divide both sides of that inequality by $p_k$, you get inequality $2^{k-1}\le 1/p_k+k$. Since $1/p_k<1$ you get $2^{k-1}<1+k$ and so on (see the answer).

Comment: Okay Thanks. Btw I have also created my solution. It uses the same approach as above but I had written that in a different and more convenient way. Anyways, thanks for helping out!

Comment: What is inconvenient in my answer?

Comment: Nope nothing is inconvenient, just saying that my solution goes with simple words. Anyways, it's your solution only from which I took my help.